# using google analytics to create custom reports for a web app

Tags: google-analytics, analytics-api

I'm curently writing a web app that's supposed to take care of analytics and traffic on the application for our users. The users should be able to log in to the application and see a special area where they can see traffic stats for say, their Profile.

Now, there might be a number of ways to get this done and i'm looking at Google Analytics as an ideal solution.

1) So, what we are planning to do is that have the users sign up for Google Analytics and just key in their Analytics UA-XXXXXXXXX code when they are registering.. and then the application could spit out required Google Analytics tracking code on that particular page (User Profile) to log traffic and analytics. But the downside to this is that while registering for Google Analytics you have to link up a domain - and you need to verify domain ownership - which would belong to us and this might become a hassle for the users.

2) We can use Google Analytics API to pull data from our personal account and throw the information out to the user when he/she logs in - Not sure how this would go since i havent yet had a look at Google Analytics API. May be this would be an ideal solution?

Is there a more elegant solution where i could create sort of buckets or containers etc inside Google Analytics for our every user and then pulling data would become easy for us.

Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The choice of going with number 1 or 2 depends on how you want your users to be able to view the data. If you want them to be able to see the full range of reports available in Google Analytics then you should use 1 but if you just want to pull out stats to show on your own site then you'll need to use the API.

You can implement a GA login for each user by using profiles in your own account. You can use the same tracking code for all users but then filter the data so it's sent to different profiles depending on which user(s) are to see stats for each page on the site. You can then give the user a login to GA where they only have access to reports from their own profile.

The main problem with this approach is that you would need to manually set up each profile and user login yourself. There would probably also be an issue with the number of profiles in your account as I think there's a limit of 50 so you could end up needing multiple accounts.

Using the API would be easier because you would just need to send all the data to your own account then filter it while you're downloading it.